# Looping 2 arrays at once in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays and the idea is to check a **house** that is for **sale** or **rent**, same goes for an **apartment**.

The problem is that it only loops the house for sale and not for rent or even the apartment.

```
$accoTypes = ["house","apartment"];
$accoPrefers = ["sale","rent"];

foreach ($accoTypes as $accoType) {

    foreach ($accoPrefers as $accoPrefer) {
```

Comment: [Loops both just fine](https://3v4l.org/jFnTF).

Comment: What is the error message or output you're getting?  Posting all of your code would help the community too.

Comment: just use `foreach ($accoTypes as $key => $accoType) {
 echo $accoType . " = " . $accoPrefers[$key];`